# sqlite database in android studio

Tags: android

can someone please help me to solve.I m new in android studio,learning. I create an application for my own purpose with sqlite storage. I created a table in sqlite database
ie,
Id  clockno.  name   age

1. how display name in textview when i enter clockno.
2. If ex. I have 2 entry that clock no.1234 and 123, when i enter clock no.123 then display its corresponding name and filling with 1234 then display its name
   all without clicking a button like search.

I am creating application in android studio in java.
pls help
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this

```
 if (textview1.getText().toString().equals("1234")) {
textview2.setText("your wordshere");
 }
```